# R Automate selecting the top 3 values for each column with function and for loop

Tags: r

Example data:

```
  df<-data.frame(Season=rep(2001:2003,each=5), A=c(1:15), B = rep(10,15), C=c(15:1), Pts = seq(150,10,-10))
  df
```

I'd like to automate a calculation for the points scored (Pts) each season, if we pick the top 3 of each of the variables A-C by season.

I can do this manually, for example for column A:

```
test<-df%>%
  group_by(Season)%>%
  slice_max(order_by = tibble(A), n=3)
  sum(test$Pts)
```

However, for B, I need a second differentiator because of the ties(otherwise it picks more than 3 rows for each season):

```
   test<-df%>%
      group_by(Season)%>%
      slice_max(order_by = tibble(B,A), n=3)
      sum(test$Pts)
```

I'd like to automate this, storing the variable and the total points along the way. I think the way forward is with a function and a for loop, but I'm not sure how to deal with the ties without leaving a couple of the variables out of the loop and using them as tie breakers. This is my best effort:

```
Topvars<-data.frame()
top<- function(colName){
  
  test<-df%>%
    group_by(Season)%>%
    slice_max(order_by = tibble({{colName}}), n=3)
  temp<-data.frame(Var = {{colName}}, Points = sum(as.numeric(test$Pts)))
  topfwd<-rbind(topfwd,temp)
  
}

for (x in colnames(df)){
  
  top(df[[x]])
}
```

This returns the error "Caused by error:! `order_by` must have size 5, not size 15." Am I referencing the data frames correctly? I've read up on https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html, and I thought I understood it. Also is there a better way to sort ties to ensure I pick only the top 3 without sacrificing some variables from the for loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df %>%
    pivot_longer(A:C)%>%
    slice_max(value, n = 3, by = c(Season, name), with_ties = FALSE) %>%
    summarise(val=sum(Pts), .by = name)

# A tibble: 3 × 2
  name    val
  <chr> <dbl>
1 A       630
2 B       810
3 C       810
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `order` with `decreasing=TRUE` which already breaks ties. Using `ave` we group the respective `cols` by `Season` and coerce all `<= 3` to `TRUE` as base from which *Pts* to calculate the `sum`.

```
> cols <- c("A", "B", "C")
> lapply(df[cols], \(x) sum(df$Pts[ave(x, df$Season, 
+                                     FUN=\(x) order(x, decreasing=TRUE)) <= 3]))
$A
[1] 630

$B
[1] 810

$C
[1] 810
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(Season = c(2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 
2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 
2003L), A = 1:15, B = c(10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10), C = 15:1, Pts = c(150, 140, 130, 120, 110, 
100, 90, 80, 70, 60, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
```